# How can I use montage to concatenate 3 images so that they form an "inverted triangle"?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to use `montage` to concatenate 3 images so that 2 are placed on top and one on the bottom in the middle, so that the overall shape of the concatenated images is kind of like an inverted triangle. I tried to do this like this:

`montage -tile 2x1 img1.png img2.png img3.png temp.png`

but I'm getting two files as a result: one with `img1.png` and `img2.png` called `temp-0.png` and another with just `img3.png` called `temp-1.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with three pictures with size 642x397 pixels.

- Simple method

  ```
  montage 00-splash.png 02-iso-testing_installed-new-version.png 05-select-device_warning-and-overview.png -tile 2x2 temp1.png
  ```

  [image]
- Advanced two-step method to get what I think you want

  ```
  montage 00-splash.png 02-iso-testing_installed-new-version.png -geometry 650x400 -tile 2x1 -auto-orient temp.png
  montage temp.png 05-select-device_warning-and-overview.png -geometry 1300x400 -tile 1x2 tmp2.png
  ```

  [image]